# Why isn't website receiving POST request?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have been trying to create reload button, Once it gets clicked, with the support of javascript form is submitted:

```
<div style="float: left;width:100%;height: 8%;background-color: #333333;min-height: 60px;">
    <form id="rel_inv" name="reload_inventory" action="/account/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="reloadinv" value="inventory_reload" style="display: none;"></input>
    <div onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('rel_inv').submit();" name="reload_inv" style="width: 60px;height: 60px;cursor: pointer;text-decoration:none;display: block;"><img src="/static/Home/images/reload_i.png" style="width: 30px;height: 30px;margin-top: 25%;margin-left: 25%;"></div>
</div>
```

When div is clicked, page gets reloaded, However i still don't receive any POST requests in views.py -

```
reload_inventory = "false"
if request.method == 'POST':
    print("request has been received")
    if request.POST.get("reloadinv"):
        reload_inventory = "true"
```

reload_inventory variable is sent to template via context. To check if variable was altered after sending POST request, I added alert to `<script>` -

```
alert("{{ reload_inventory }}")
```

Script was always alerting "false", and request.method was never POST when form was submitted...

---

Final goal is to use `{{ reload_inventory }}` variable to get whether user requested inventory reload or not. If `{{ reload_inventory }}` was `"true"`, Inventory function would be called and User's inventory would open up automatically.

More simply, Once user clicks reload button, the page is reloaded with the new variable `reload_inventory`. If `reload_inventory` is "true", Inventory menu would be opened via javascript, If not, vice versa.

---

So what could the problem be? Is there reason behind why request.method is not equal to POST even when form is submitted? Is there any better way of doing this? Is there something wrong with my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code in that div looks very whacky. Also, it should be in a JavaScript file so that it can be edited and tooled properly.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Even without div, The submit input itself gave same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
if request.POST.get("reload_inv"):
```

The `POST` dictionary does not contain such a value. You can put a `print(request.POST)` after `print("request has been received")` and check it out.

Instead, all `POST` key-value pairs are filled with form data (not javasciript ones). The `reload_inv` variable is the name of the `div` (`<div onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('rel_inv').submit();" name="reload_inv">...</div>`), which actually it's not valid HTML.

In order to work, change `if request.POST.get("reload_inv"):` to:

```
if request.POST.get("reloadinv"):
```

which is the name of your `input` (`<input type="submit" name="reloadinv" value="inventory_reload" ...>`)

[EDIT]: In addition, there is no point of having an `<input type="submit">` when you submit your form with another element (`div`). Instead, change this input from:

```
<input type="submit" name="reloadinv" value="inventory_reload" style="display: none;"></input>
```

to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="reloadinv" value="inventory_reload">
```

I tested it locally and works great.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I tried it and still didn't receive any request.  request.method was not equal to "POST" for some reason. Can it be some kind of bug?

Comment: Updated my answer. The reason behind the request is not `POST` is another question. I copy-pasted your code locally and works great (with the 2 changes that appear in my answer: `if request.POST.get("reloadinv"):` and `<input type="hidden" name="reloadinv" value="inventory_reload">`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! `<input type="hidden">` seems to work perfectly for some reason.